# rapidcheck generator for a struct with a c style array as member

Tags: c++, struct, property-based-testing

Suppose I have the following struct:

```
struct Data {
    float zs[50];
};
```

I'm trying to create a rapidcheck generator similarly to the ones defined [here](https://github.com/emil-e/rapidcheck/blob/master/doc/generators.md) such as:

```
// NOTE: Must be in rc namespace!
namespace rc {

template<>
struct Arbitrary<Person> {
  static Gen<Person> arbitrary() {
    return gen::build<Person>(
        gen::set(&Person::firstName),
        gen::set(&Person::lastName),
        gen::set(&Person::age, gen::inRange(0, 100)));
  }
};

} // namespace rc
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Something didn't work with your link *here*

Comment: I made an edit.